# What are the mandatory files for PHPMailer?

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

While I was finding a way to send a mail with PHP,
I found the default mail() function in PHP, the Pear, and PHPMailer.

I was told that mail() function has many limitations,
so I read a tutorial of Pear but I found that it needs installation.
(My host service restricts library installation)

The last one, PHPMailer seems consist of php files and some documents.

So I would like to know that it does not need installation, just copy.

So I ask you that if I just copy some php files of the PHPMailer to use it.

If so, can I know some mandatory files to be copied?
I want to keep minimal number of files in my small account.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you read the PHPMailer documentation? That's where I'd start.

Comment: PHPMailer itself is a pretty small class, I suppose It depends on how you're sending the emails, e.g. POP3, SMTP. But you're talking almost kilobytes here.

Answer (score 3):

Download [PHPMailer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/), and the only file you need is `class.phpmailer.php`.

Include it with:

```
require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
```

and then follow the example code to send your mail. That's all you need to get started :)

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->SetFrom('you@yourdomain.com');
$mail->AddAddress('you@yourdomain.com');
$mail->Subject = "Test";
$mail->Body = "Testing PHPMailer.";

if(!$mail->Send()) echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
else echo "Message sent!"
```